# Question on Queueable interface

Tags: apex, callout

I have a class implements Queueable interface.

1.Do I have to annotate the method with @future in my class?

I received "Callout not allowed from this future method. Please enable callout by annotating the future method." when I didn't annotate. But my understanding is that this interface is a alternative of @future.

2. How do I also implement Scheduable interface in this class? I got "Queueable cannot be implemented with other system interfaces."

Here's the code:

```
global class Example implements Queueable,scheduable{

public void execute(SchedulableContext SC){


}
public void execute(QueueableContext context){

   testCall();
}

void testCall()
{
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(Endpoint);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml' );
        req.setBody(body);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        if(res.getStatusCode()==200)
        {
            String resDoc = res.getBody();
            System.debug(resDoc);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Separate classes for schedule and que, @future(CALLOUT=TRUE), https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/10/new-apex-queueable-interface.html

Comment: @Eric I figured out the first problem can be resolved by adding implements Database.AllowsCallouts so I don't need to annotate the callout methods